# Is there a direct way to target empty grid cells (.) in a grid-template-areas?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Let's say you have `grid-template-areas` that look like this

```
 .grid {
   grid-template-areas: 
   ". . a a a a a . ."
   ". . b b c c c . ."
   ". . b b c c c . ."
   }
```

Is there a way to target the css for the `.` cells to make them a different background color for example?

Comment: No...CSS-grid areas are **not elements** and so cannot be selected with CSS.

Comment: Thanks, I was curious to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unnamed grid areas in `grid-template-areas` are CSS. So you're asking if there's a way to target CSS with CSS. The answer would be no. CSS is used to target HTML. (Although an argument could be made with regard to CSS pseudo-elements).

Here are three ways to work around the problem:

1. Create "empty" targetable HTML elements.

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 30px 30px 30px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(9, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-template-areas: 
   "x x a a a a a y y"
   "x x b b c c c y y"
   "x x b b c c c y y";
}
   
header        { grid-area: a; background-color: lightgreen; }
article       { grid-area: b; background-color: pink; }
aside         { grid-area: c; background-color: aqua; }
.empty-area-1 { grid-area: x; background-color: gray; }
.empty-area-2 { grid-area: y; background-color: gray; }
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="empty-area-1"></div>
  <header>header</header>
  <article>content</article>
  <aside>aside</aside>
  <div class="empty-area-2"></div>
</main>
```

2. Create "empty" targetable CSS pseudo-elements.

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 30px 30px 30px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(9, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-template-areas: 
   "x x a a a a a y y"
   "x x b b c c c y y"
   "x x b b c c c y y";
}

main::before {
  grid-area: x;
  background-color: gray; 
  content: "";
}

main::after {
  grid-area: y;
  background-color: gray;
  content: "";
}
   
header        { grid-area: a; background-color: lightgreen; }
article       { grid-area: b; background-color: pink; }
aside         { grid-area: c; background-color: aqua; }
```

```html
<main>
  <header>header</header>
  <article>content</article>
  <aside>aside</aside>
</main>
```

3. If the targeting is limited to background color, then apply the color to the container:

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 30px 30px 30px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(9, 1fr);
  background-color: gray;
  grid-template-areas: 
   ". . a a a a a . ."
   ". . b b c c c . ."
   ". . b b c c c . .";
}
   
header  { grid-area: a; background-color: lightgreen; }
article { grid-area: b; background-color: pink; }
aside   { grid-area: c; background-color: aqua; }
```

```html
<main>
  <header>header</header>
  <article>content</article>
  <aside>aside</aside>
</main>
```